# Switch the most Odd Ones 8 (Advanced)

Tags: pattern, odd-one-out

[image]

Two similar but independent patterns has gotten one out of nine parts misplaced with the other pattern. What two figures (one in range a-i and the other in range 1-9) are the most odd ones that should be switched back to restore both patterns, and why?

*Created by myself*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> On the left picture its the far right on the middle row which has to be switched with the middle box in the bottom row in the right picture. (f and 8)

or

> On the left picture its the middle box in the bottom row which has to be switched with the far right box on the middle row in the right picture. (h and 6)

because

> The boxes have to be the same from top right to bottom left
>  [image]

but if you want to get just ONE answer

> I'll go with the blue circled one

because

> Then there are always exactly two rows with rectangles in each of the boxes. Otherwise it would be "more" odd if on side had 3 rows with boxes including rectangles and the other just 1 row.

Comment: Great! Your red option is actually what I intended being the correct answer, mostly based on how the inner figures is rotated around the center origin of the figures going from left to right and from top to bottom.

Comment: oh wow, but I will stay with the blue one (because editing the question after you know the answer... not cool). Your "riddles" are fun :-)